# Can't use QuickCheck because of clock_getres's InvalidArgument Exception

Tags: haskell-stack, quickcheck

Using Stack GHCi on Ubuntu Linux (Windows Subsystem Layer), I can't use any aspect of Test.QuickCheck, even though I can build it and import it. I've been using Haskell in this way for a while without issue.

The simplest failing case sums it up nicely. After successfully loading and importing QuickCheck, I try the following:

Prelude Test.QuickCheck> sample (arbitrary :: Gen Int)

I get the following:

*** Exception: clock_getres: invalid argument (Invalid argument)

This is the same error that I get in every attempted use of quickCheck, property, sample...It doesn't matter if I import QuickCheck or link it with a .cabal file. These functions all still type check, too.

"clock_getres" has something to do with Linux, so I tried using System.Random, which worked fine. Does anybody know what might be causing most of QuickCheck's functions to fail?

Comment: I am having this same issue: using QuickCheck-2.13.2 with GHCI 8.7.20181217 on Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS on Windows 10 17134. When using GHCI 8.0.2, I did not have this issue.

Comment: Having that as well: ` 4.4.0-17134-Microsoft #1130-Microsoft Thu Nov 07 15:21:00 PST 2019 x86_64 GNU/Linux` (arch linux) when running specs tests from `https://exercism.io/my/tracks/haskell` with ghci version 8.8.3 and cabal version 3.0.0.0.